# how to check if the current value exist in a particular element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a drop-down menu. I was trying to get the current `li` value using jQuery. Is there any way that we can get the current value of the current `li` or any other smarter way to do that.

My JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17/

Comment: see my answer please, I've showed you how to do it without changing much of your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove spaces

```js
$('.languageDropdown li').on('click', function(){

var reg = /^\s*|\s*$/g;  
alert("=="+$(this).text()+"==");
var text = $(this).text().replace(reg, "");


 if( text === 'ENGLISH'){
  alert('you just clicked english');
 }
 else{
  alert('wrong value');
 }
 
});
```

```css
a{
  font-size:12px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a{
  padding-left:20px;
}
li a:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="language">
        <a href="#">
           ENG 
        </a>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <ul class="languageDropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            ENGLISH
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            SPANISH
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            ARABIC
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            TELUGU
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Ying Yi can you please explain in details what you did in the code.

Comment: You need to remove spaces.

Answer (score 1):

.text() usually returns a bunch of whitespaces around the actual value, so it's better to compare them something like this.

```
if ($(this).text().trim() === 'ENGLISH')
```

Or, better yet, add an attribute to the tag itself, so you can identify the value even when the text is in other languages.

```
<li value="english">
  <a href="#">
      'ENGLISH' in some other language
  </a>
</li>

if ($(this).attr("value") === "english")
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other said, `.text()` returns lots of unnecessary white spaces (which should be some HTML tags), for example `<li><a>123</a></li>` will return `{bunch of spaces}123{bunch of spaces}` because the anchor tag `a` has been replaced by spaces, there would be no such kind of spaces if we use `$("li a").text()` instead since there is no HTML tag replacement occur.

However, I personally use `.text()` as value comparison rarely. The better practice would be using the `data-*` attr of elements, avoid missing the `data-` prefix if it is a make up attr to prevent confuse other programmer.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/o2gxgz9r/19/

```js
var AcceptedValues = ["english", "abc"],
    ListItems = $(".languageDropdown li").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr("data-value", $this.text().trim().toLowerCase()); // Bind their text to data-value
    }).on("click", function () {
      var $this = $(this),
          Value = $this.attr("data-value");

      if ($.inArray(Value, AcceptedValues) >= 0) // Search if the value inside the array
        alert("You just clicked '" + Value.toUpperCase() + "'");
      else alert("Wrong value");
    });
```

```css
a{
  font-size:12px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a{
  padding-left:20px;
}
li a:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="language">
        <a href="#">
           ENG 
        </a>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <ul class="languageDropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            ABC
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            ENGLISH
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            SPANISH
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            ARABIC
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            TELUGU
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good point @Ying Yi, about removing spaces.

Then this should work by just adding the trim() as well:

```
$('.languageDropdown li').on('click', function(){
if( $(this).text().trim() === 'ENGLISH'){
    alert('you just clicked english');
}
else{
    alert('wrong value');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to get the first child of the `<li>` element, then get the innerHTML of it. You can do this without changing much of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbmatxw/

```
$('.languageDropdown li').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).children().get(0).innerHTML.trim() === 'ENGLISH'){
        alert('you just clicked english');
    }
    else{
        alert('wrong value');
    }
});
```